# Static player, scrolling background

Tags: java

Okay, I've been following a tutorial and I like where it's got me. Although the character is the one who moves and the background scrolls with it. Is there a way with the code below I can reverse that?

```
public class Background {

    private int bgX, bgY, speedX;

    public Background(int x, int y) {
        bgX = x;
        bgY = y;
        speedX = 0;
    }

    public void update() {
        bgX += speedX;

        if (bgX <= -2160) {
            bgX += 4320;
        }
    }

    public int getBgX() {
        return bgX;
    }

    public int getBgY() {
        return bgY;
    }

    public int getSpeedX() {
        return speedX;
    }

    public void setBgX(int bgX) {
        this.bgX = bgX;
    }

    public void setBgY(int bgY) {
        this.bgY = bgY;
    }

    public void setSpeedX(int speedX) {
        this.speedX = speedX;
    }

}
```

And this is the character:

```
public void update() {
        // Moves Character or Scrolls Background accordingly.

        if (speedX < 0) {
            centerX += speedX;
        }
        if (speedX == 0 || speedX < 0) {
            bg1.setSpeedX(0);
            bg2.setSpeedX(0);

        }
        if (centerX <= 200 && speedX > 0) {
            centerX += speedX;
        }
        if (speedX > 0 && centerX > 200) {
            bg1.setSpeedX(-MOVESPEED / 5);
            bg2.setSpeedX(-MOVESPEED / 5);
        }

        // Updates Y Position
        centerY += speedY;

        // Handles Jumping

            speedY += 1;

        if (speedY > 3){
            jumped = true;
        }

        // Prevents going beyond X coordinate of 0
        if (centerX + speedX <= 60) {
            centerX = 61;
        }

        rect.set(centerX - 34, centerY - 63, centerX + 34, centerY);
        rect2.set(rect.left, rect.top + 63, rect.left+68, rect.top + 128);
        rect3.set(rect.left - 26, rect.top+32, rect.left, rect.top+52);
        rect4.set(rect.left + 68, rect.top+32, rect.left+94, rect.top+52);
        yellowRed.set(centerX - 110, centerY - 110, centerX + 70, centerY + 70);
        footleft.set(centerX - 50, centerY + 20, centerX, centerY + 35);
        footright.set(centerX, centerY + 20, centerX+50, centerY+35);


    }
```

I'm pretty confident with Java, but "stuff like this" is new to me.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: How I can modify this so instead of the character making the background scroll and instead I'd like the background to scroll from the start without needing the character to move to scroll it.

Comment: This question is pretty broad. You're asking us to go through your code and rewrite it for you. Ultimately this is more of a logic issue than a java specific problem (you figure out how to build the birdhouse first, and worry about how to use the hammer later, to use an analogy). It would be better to ask a more specific question; give it a try yourself first and post when / if you encounter an issue or have a question that has not already been asked here before.

Comment: Can we see the rest of the code (particular the driver/main where the character and background are actually being updated)?  Also, the question in the post is different from the on the comments section.  I would edit the question to be more specific.

Comment: You should also be having a class GameScreen or something. In the update method of the GameScreen, you should just add character.MoveRight() or something. In the Character's MoveRight(), handle the logic behind the moving